# How do you get your app to appear on the Facebook Mobile Application? (specifically iPhone)

Tags: iphone, facebook-canvas

We have a popular Facebook Application and a version of our App for the iPhone.  I was wondering how we can make our Application appear in the "Apps" Section on the new Facebook iPhone app.  On my iPhone I currently see links to the App store for Pixable, Badoo, Airbnb, Foursquare and WhoisNear iPhone Application.

I have filled out the Native iOS App settings in the Developer section on Facebook (including adding the Bundle ID and the iPhone app store ID) several weeks ago thinking it took a while to update, but still nothing shows up on my iPhone app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Best,
M

Screenshot of where we want our app to show up:

[image: http://imgur.com/GIEHP]

Comment: So the solution to the problem is to enable the "Configured for iOS SSO" setting in the Application Settings.  Even though our apps aren't SSO enabled (yet), once "Enabled" is checked and saved, the app will appear in the Apps section of Facebook's iPhone app.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your Application Settings and on the Basic Settings specify a Mobile Web URL for your Mobile Web integration. You should be able to set the URL to your app's iTunes URL.

Answer (score 0):

Fill out the iOS information within the admin settings of your application, which also means they are using the same application id.  You also have to have granted at least the basic permissions via connect on the app, and have the app installed on the phone.